# How to assign first two characters in a string to a variable in C (Arduino)

Tags: c, string, char, arduino, character

I have an Arduino project with a string, called `string`, which is four digits, each between 0 and 9.  So for example, a possible value is `1200`.  I'd like to take the first character, `1`, and assign it to another string, called `xCo`.

```
  String string = String(c);
  String xCo = String(string[0]);
  Serial.print(xCo);
```

Strangely, the `Serial.print(xCo);` line doesn't just print the first character, `1`.  Rather, it prints the whole `string`. I've read other questions' answers and they said that to reference a particular character, you just choose the index number of that character by doing something like `string[0]`.  Yet, this isn't working for me.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**  As the commenters have pointed out, `String` is an Arduino type, at least I'm pretty sure.  My C and Arduino experience is very limited, so I can't be sure.

Comment: What is the type declaration of `String`? Including that would clarify your question a lot. Also, is this actually C, or C++? Two rather different languages.

Comment: Are you using the `String` object from the Arduino libraries? If so, you really should tag your question with something Arduino-related. Just calling it a "string" in "C" will confuse many people, who are used to dealing with strings in C differently.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm assuming it's C, just because I'm pretty sure that's the standard language used by Arduino, but like I said in the question I'm very new to both C and Arduino, so I can't be certain. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the value of a character at a given position in a string, use [charAt()](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringCharAt).

```cpp
String string = "1200";
char singleCharacter = string.charAt(0);
Serial.print(singleCharacter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of people recommends to not use String. The best way is to simply use `char *`

```
char *foo = "1200";
char c = foo[0];
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but it seems to print out the entire *foo, rather than just the first character.        `char c = BTLEserial.read();   
      char *foo = &c;
      char first = foo[0];
      Serial.println(first);`

Comment: I don't undrestand what you are doing, in your code there is no null terminated char array. Only only manipulate one `char`, no `char *`